# FXyz3D: How to get started

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-3d

I have downloaded the FXyz3D package, and got that colourful spiral in no time by copying the code from the GitHub page, but ... what else can I do with this package, which looks interesting? There seems to be no manual...

Using FXyz3D, could I triangulate x,y indexed data representing Depth Z and display the resulting surface like in the figure attached? (and indeed how to display the seismic shown in the background?). Is this the right tool for this kind of 3D viewing?

Many thanks - Michael

[image]

Comment: You likely noticed the samples at https://github.com/FXyz/FXyz/tree/master/Fxyz-Samples - reading their code could be a starting point...

Comment: Whether you have a mathematical function f(x,y) or a file with x,y,z values you can generate a [`SurfacePlotMesh`](https://github.com/FXyz/FXyz/blob/master/FXyz-Core/src/main/java/org/fxyz3d/shapes/primitives/SurfacePlotMesh.java), with a colored density map as texture. Please provide more details of what you try to achieve.

Comment: Try the devnexus talk on this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qZBa_tIBrRE&feature=youtu.be&t=5837